# how much time it takes for a flute to start making sound?

Tags: acoustics

sound as i understand is created in a flute by ; the compressions imparted to the air inside the flute . the blowed air is also sometimes not allowed to enter the flute due to its regular contact with the air wave inside the flute (please correct me).

so by the time we start hearing the sound of the flute how much compressions are present in the air at that time , or does it start at the time a single compression is imparted to the air inside the flute ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Study that a bit more, some of the question content is really well mapped even online (google aerophones, edge-blown aerophones, flute etc.).

The problem is that at the beginning of sound production, there is no regular oscillations of the air inside the flute - it must be developed. The motion of the air column rises usually from the vortex generated edge-tones (sometimes it's almost noise-like driving from which the harmonics rises). The detailed physics is rather complicated. See e.g. Howe's *Theory of vortex sound* if you are interested.

The time scales of so called transient (in this case: the transition from steady to acoustically unsteady regular airflow) takes generally tens of the resulting sound periods, but there is a huge influence by the player's skill. 20-30 $T$ are usual for flue organ pipes (i.e. something player can't really affect).